# Any way to make sessionStorage reactive in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, session-storage

Lets say I built an app, that fetches data through `axios.get` from a database every time it loads or is refreshed. This makes the app slow, so I want to only get the data in the `initial load` of the app and put it into `sessionStorage`.

Problem is that `sessionStorage` is not reactive. When I do this:

```
const state = reactive({
    image: sessionStorage.image
})
```

and want to render:

```
  <div class="home-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + state.image + ')'}"></div>
```

it only works, if the `sessionStorage` has been updated in the previous page load. For the initial page load `state.image` throws a `404 not found`.

Is there any way to make `sessionStorage` reactive? I've read about `watchers`, `set` and `get` but can't quite figure it out.

**Solution (new):**

Aaaaactually, I just found a way to make `sessionStorage` behave as if it was `reactive` during `initial load` and I don't even need `vuex` for it:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
    image: sessionStorage.image || ""
})

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[0]
        state.image = sessionStorage.image = 'storage/' + data['image']
    })
</script>
```

This way the `reactive` function chooses an empty string, if `sessionStorage` is undefined during the initial load and assigns value from `axios.get` to `sessionStorage`. On all consecutive page loads, the `reactive` function uses `sessionStorage`, which now has a value assigned to it.

Coding is fun. Sometimes you learn how to replace 100 lines of code with 1 LOC.

**Solution (old):**

Ok, now my storage works how I want it to. It is `global`, `reactive`, `persistent` and easy to use. I will accept @Elsa's answer because she helped me look into `vuex`.

I created a `store` in a seperate **`store.js`** file:

```
import {createStore} from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            image: sessionStorage.image || ""
        }
    }
})
export default store
```

then register it in **`app.js`**:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from "../vue/app";
import store from "./store";

createApp(app)
    .use(store)
    .mount("#app");
```

and now I can use `store` in my components like so:

```
<template>
  <section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="home-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + store.state.image + ')'}"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>


<script setup>
import {useStore} from "vuex";

const store = useStore()

if (!sessionStorage.image) {
    axios.get('/home')
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data[0]
            store.state.image = sessionStorage.image = 'storage/' + data['image']
        })
}
</script>
```

The `axios` request runs only if `sessionStorage.image` is undefined, otherwise its value is rendered directly. If the link exists, the image does not get newly loaded in the template first, but rendered instantly.

I might omit `state = reactive` completely now, since I can use `store.state` instead globally and even link it to `ss/ls`. The only thing I have to maintain is the fields inside:

```
const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            image: sessionStorage.image || ""
        }
    }
})
```

because `vue` throws `404 errors` if I don't (but renders the elements anyway because of reactivity).

Comment: No, you can't make sessionStorage reactive in that way. But, this is quite literally the use case for [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)!

Comment: Why not using the provide and inject?

Comment: @huanfeng I'd prefer using a `global reactive storage` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a week ago and I try 3 ways to make a sessionStorage reactive in vue3.
1.vuex
2.create event listener
3.setInterval

I found a temporary solution for my problem with setInterval.

1.vuex

```
const state = () => {
  return {
    latInfo: sessionStorage.getItem('lat') || 0
  }
}

const getters = {
  latInfo: state => state.latInfo
}
```

3.setInterval

```
  setup() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (infoData) {
        infoData.lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat')
      }
    }, 1000)
```

Comment: ur welcome. yes, I looked at your solution. there are several solutions to this question. honestly, I have to use setInterval for my project because I need to reactive with the script part into the HTML page. and I'm so happy that I was able to help you with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, sessionStorage cannot be reactive.

If my understanding correct, you just want a global variable to be reactive. You can simply achieve it via provide and inject:

```
const yourGlobalVar = sessionStorage.getItem('image');
app.provide('yourImage', ref(yourGlobalVar))
```

Where used it:

```
setup(){
   ...
   const image = inject('yourImage');
   ...
   return {image}
}
```

Comment: My main problem is that I need a `persistent variable` which can also be used `reactively`. I don't know how to achieve this without `sessionStorage/localStorage`. There seems to be a way to create `global variables` in `composition api` and pass them around but there seems to be no way to make them `persistent`.

Comment: You can add a layer to provide a get/set, every time after getting the data from storage and change the value of global variable, and before setting data to storage, update the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

VueUse is doing it, take a look at [useStorage()](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/) method